# What is the difference between snaps and Ubuntu Software Center-based apps?

Tags: software-center, snap

I have my Ubuntu Software Center set up to display available snaps. Some apps have both a snap version and an Ubuntu Software Center version available. However, I don't know what the difference is between them. I've seen rumors that snaps are self-updating, but I don't know if Ubuntu Software Center apps can do that, too. In general, I'm wondering what the differences and pros/cons are between the two.

Comment: Ubuntu software centre contains apps provided by Ubuntu official repositories as well as snap.Software center is just a GUI method to install apps if you want to avoid CLI method. If an update is there, it will be delivered by GUI as well as CLI. So, Software center is just a front end.

Comment: Not a duplicate, and the answer below is spot on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Classic packages

If you're installing a program from deb-package (Ubuntu Software Center version in the question), you get a program that relies on system-installed dependencies.

**Pro:** you only download every common part once.

**Con:** you can't install programs that require something that is newer than available for your system release.

### Snaps (snap packages)

If you're installing a program from snap, you get a program with all its dependencies packed in isolated container.

**Pro:** you can install programs that require dependencies that are not available system-wide, or use programs with different versions of same dependencies.

**Cons:**

- you have to download and keep same components again, so you could get increased traffic and disk usage.
- if there is vulnerability found in some dependency, you have to wait while program publisher updates snap with updated one, while you could update it yourself if you'd used classic packages.