# how to uninstall extra opera app in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: uninstall, opera

Using Ubuntu 20.04.3 lts.

In ubuntu software, I only show 1 icon for opera, but in apps menu, 9dots, I see 2 opera icons. i can open both at same time. One says ver 80... for core 18,
and 2nd icon shows ver 68... core 20.04.3.

How to uninstall core 18 version only? under opera help, about, the install says:
/snap/opera/145/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera (ver 80)

and:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera (ver 68)

Comment: How did you install Opera?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are the two versions of Chromium and VLC available in Ubuntu software of different sizes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119929/why-are-the-two-versions-of-chromium-and-vlc-available-in-ubuntu-software-of-dif)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is uninstall everything, and install opera again form the ubuntu software.

If you are downloading software form the ubuntu software, make sure that you get the latest/stable, also, make sure that the opera you are downloading is the official one. Both can be seen in the ubuntu software:

[image: ubuntu store on opera]

Make sure that you check the source (top right) and the developer (bottom), as well as its certification.

When I did this, only one downloaded.

Edit:

Yes, I know this only downloads the latest, you can download the .deb package from https://www.opera.com/download#opera-browser and install them from there. The process is you download it to the downloads folder, and open it with the package manager (Ubuntu software works). If you download a snap package, it downloads everything.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how to uninstall only one (older) version of the software already on the system.

Comment: I hope I fixed it @ZeissIkon

Comment: Better, @Alex; better.